# Delphi subtraction error? How can fix this?

Tags: delphi

I have code like :

```
debt:=debt+(p_sum-p_addition-p_paid);
```

before this line

```
debt:=0;
p_sum:=36;
p_addition:=3.6;
p_paid:=32.4;
```

after this line debt variable gets value like : 1.3322676e-15;

[image]

Comment: This is NOT an error. This is expected. Floating-point arithmetics isn't exact. Surely you can live with an error of some 10^-15?

Comment: lets take it is expected, how can i get result back normal format?

Comment: "Normal format" only matters when the data is being displayed, which you can do with `FloatToStr` or the `Format` function. The amount stored in the variable is fine as it is (although if you're dealing with currency values it's better to use the `Currency` type instead, which helps prevent losing fractions of a cent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using binary floating point arithmetic. Your non-integer values, are not representable in binary floating point. And hence you are subject to rounding errors.

You actually want to operate with decimal rather than binary representations. If you do that then your values will all be represented exactly and the arithmetic will be exact.

In Delphi, the decimal real valued data type is Currency. I suggest that you switch to Currency for these calculations.

Required reading on this topic is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is simply scientific notation for a floating point value. This is just one of a few different ways of displaying the value in the Watch List. In this case the "normal format" would be: 0.0000000000000013322676 (Note there are 15 zeroes.) The Watch List has a limit of 18 digits to display the value. So in the interests of giving you ***the programmer*** a value as accurate as possible, it uses the scientific notation.

Whenever a floating point number is very small (as in this case) or very large, it is much more efficient to display it in scientific notation. The reason your calculation produces this very small result instead of 0 is due to rounding error as explained in [David's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20292474/224704).

As for getting the value "back to normal format", there's no point. The value is simply a value in memory representing the result of a calculation. Basically a series of bytes (in this particular case $3B $AA $11 $F7 $FF $FF $D7 $3C). You don't want to fiddle with this value, otherwise you might introduce more rounding errors. Also, as a programmer you should be able to read the more accurate scientific notation.

However, at some point you may want to display this value to your ***users***. In which case you will create an appropriate string representation of the value. The most appropriate format will depend on the nature of your application. (I.e. scientific notation will still be best in some cases.)

If you want to use fixed floating point notation, you could use `FormatFloat('0.00', Value);` In your case the very small number will be rounded to `0.00`. (BTW, you can even put that into your Watch List.)
Read the help on `FormatFloat` for more information. You can choose to include/exclude thousand separators, or even use scientific notation in your own display format.

#### Reading Scientific Notation

Scientific notation is actually quite easy to read once you understand the format:
`Number`e`Exponent` E.g. `1.3322676`e`-15`

This basically means: take the `Number` and multiply it by 10 to the power of `Exponent`. (This equates to shifting the decimal point left/right `Exponent` number of digits.) A negative exponent makes the number smaller and a positive exponent makes the number bigger.

Some examples:

- 1 nanosecond is 1.0e-9 seconds, or 0.000000001 seconds
- 1 second is 1.0e+9 nanoseconds, or 100000000 nanoseconds
- 1.5e0 = 1.5
- 1.5e1 = 15
- 1.5e-1 = 0.15

An important convention of scientific notation is that the number before the exponent always uses exactly 1 digit (non-zero) to the left of the decimal point (with the exponent having been adjusted accordingly). This makes it easy to compare the relative size of two numbers just by looking at the exponent. E.g.

- 1.01846e+7 is bigger than 9.999999999e+6
- 1.01846e-6 is bigger than 9.999999999e-7
- 1.234e+250 is much bigger than 9.876e-250
- 1.234e+3 is bigger than 1.1234e+3 (only when exponents are equal would you need to compare the actual numbers).